# Googletest - check failure locally?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I would like to know, whether it is possible to check failed `ASSERT` or `EXPECT` statement that happened inside a called function and is independent of any other or previous failed `ASSERT`/`EXPECT` statement. Basically:

```
void subcheck () {
  EXPECT_EQ(1,1);
}

void check () {
  EXPECT_EQ(1,2);

  subcheck();
  //Here I want to determine whether subcheck had failure
}
```

I cannot ask on *TestFailure*, because there is a failure prior to the `subcheck`. Also, I would like to avoid workarounds like having the function to return `bool`, because that complicates `ASSERT` and has other complications.

Is there a way to do that? Launching that function in separate thread or resetting the failure flag?

Comment: [`(ASSERT|EXPECT)_NO_FATAL_FAILURE`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#asserting-on-subroutines)? This only works for fatal failures tho.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned in a comment from @Yksisarvinen, you could use `EXPECT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE` macro (or its `ASSERT` counterpart). This works even if the `subcheck` routine contains **only** non-fatal assertions. In case of your example, here is how you would check it:

```
void subcheck () {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 3) << "This failed"; // Will be printed
}

void check () {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 2);

    EXPECT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE(subcheck()) << "This failed"; // Will not be printed although it compiles
}
```

The output is:

```
/path/to/test.cpp:580: Failure
Value of: 2
Expected: 1
/path/to/test.cpp:582 Failure
Value of: 3
Expected: 1
This failed
```

Another approach you could do is to use `testing::AssertionResult`. Here is an example:

```
testing::AssertionResult subcheck2 () {
    return 1 == 3 ? testing::AssertionSuccess() : testing::AssertionFailure();
}

void check ()
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 2);

    EXPECT_EQ(testing::AssertionSuccess(), subcheck2()) << "This failed"; // Will be printed
}
```

This time, the output looks like:

```
/path/to/test.cpp:580: Failure
Value of: 2
Expected: 1
/path/to/test.cpp:582: Failure
Value of: subcheck2()
  Actual: 0
Expected: testing::AssertionSuccess()
Which is: 1
This failed
```

With all this being said, I would suggest you reconsider your testing strategy since it sounds like your tests are too complicated. Following the "One ASSERT Rule" can be hard and not always feasable, but you still strive to it whenever possible. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to work on EXPECT inside subcheck(), only reacts on ASSERT.

Comment: @TStancek It is possible that this behavior differs depending on the googletest version. I tested this behavior with version 1.7.0 and it works as described in my answer.

Comment: Try it with output, like : EXPECT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE(subcheck()) << "This routine failed"
.
 Nothing is outputed when EXPECT fails, but the message is printed if ASSERT fails. At least in my project it does.

Comment: @TStancek Please check my updated answer. By the way, what version of googletest are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that (after weekend)

Comment: @TStancek Did you try out the changes in the edited answer? Consider upvoting/marking as accepted if the answer was helpful to you.

Comment: Well, no, used GTest version is a project setting and it is set to always update to the latest version there is, so I guess we are using 1.8.1, so probably newer than yours. Therefore it makes sense that the function does what is in its description. Whether they changed it or it was a bug I dont know, but currently it seems to be not behaving the way you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `EXPECT_EQ` then `ASSERT_EQ`.

```
void subcheck () {
  // show all failure in a single run
  EXPECT_EQ(1,0);
  EXPECT_EQ(1,2);

  // make sure ASSERT_NO_FATAL_ERROR works
  ASSERT_EQ(1,0);
  ASSERT_EQ(1,2);
}
```